# How to change app name and keep current users?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

In some countries my app name have a very bad reputation. So I decided to change app name.

If I follow this steps:

1. Change bundle ID
2. Change app name in info.plist
3. Upload new binary to app store connect
4. Change app name in app store connect

These steps are enough to change the app name? I have not forgotten anything?

If yes, will I be able to keep my current users? If yes, app name will be changed to new one on their device?

Comment: Changing bundle ID will make a new app. You can change Display name.

Comment: Don't change Bundle ID. change plist Display name whatever you want to and upload the new version on a store. it's fulfil ur all requirement.

Comment: just change the display name. thats it. ah, and the name on iTunes too

Comment: Keeping the same Bundle ID means it's the same app with a different name. You will still have your ratings and reviews. The reputation came from the app itself, I dont know if this is because of errors, content, concept or whatever but if its the same app, changing the name wont improve it. Try to address the issues instead

Comment: I do not want to lose my ratings and reviews. 
Average rating of the application 4.8. I want to change only the name of the application on the app store, and on the device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't change your app bundle ID.

You need 2 steps.

Step 1)Change app name in Xcode. Go to Targets->Build Settings->Product Name, change app display name here

[image]

Step 2)Change app in AppStore Connect. For this you need to create new version of your app(It's mandatory).

See this below screen shot

[image]

And finally change your app search keywords.

Answer (score 0):

To keep your existing users but changing the app name as per your problem:

1. Change the display name in XCode, it will change the name on users' device
2. Change the name on App store connect, it will change the name on app store download and search screen
3. Possibly you might also want to change the logo (app icon) as well (change on app store as well as xcode, with latest xcode you don't need to change the icon on app store, changing on xcode only will work)
4. You can also think about changing the search keywords as well, but that depends.

And to this changes you'll obviously have to upload a new binary to app store.